# Role of Hyperledger Fabric cli container

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to run Hyperledger Fabric first-network. I have a couple of question.

1. What is the role of CLI container? Is it possible to run the fabric network without CLI container?
2. if no, then `docker-compose-couch.YAML` file does not have cli as service. How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you could perform all the necessary operation without CLI**. Like -

- Create Channel
- Join Channel
- Install Chaincode
- Instantiate Chaincode
- Invoke Chaincode
- Query

In layman terms CLI is there to facilitate you all these functionality in easy manner, because to perform above mentioned operation you need to have some dependent files **(e.g - crypto-config,chaincode,channel-artifacts)** on accessible place/container, in this case all these files are provided by CLI. You could check below mentioned volume mapped in **docker-compose-cli.yaml** file.

```
volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
```

Like to create channel,join channel you will have to access .tx file, to install chaincode you need to access specific chaincode on every peer you want to install, one thing would like to mentioned, chaincode you only instantiate once on a single peer and later on you have to install the chaincode.

Hope it would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The role of the CLI container is to make all the operations regarding the channel and network. The cli container contains the tools necessary for it, like the fabric ca client, the configtxgen and JQ. Yes its possible to run the network without it.
2. I guess you are talking about the byfn network. You can do all the necessary operations without the CLI container. Of course you will need the tools for it as mentioned above or do all the operations using the fabric SDK.